# how to use data annotations to convert int ID to string ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework code first approach and would like to have a class with a string that increments as my Id. I have the following code in my sql server that will do this for me but I cannot do the update-database in Package Manager, if I do it will erase the class attribute for the incrementing string. Here is the Sql code:

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[School](
   [SchoolID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   Emp_ID as 'emp_' + cast(SchoolID as nvarchar(10))Persisted,
   [DayEvent] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
   [DayNote] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.School] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
   [SchoolID] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
  ) ON [PRIMARY]

  GO
```

Comment: How exactly do you "increment" a string?

Comment: It best if you keep your values as native types throughout your application until the time it leaves your domain (via html, json, xml etc).  Otherwise you run into problems trying to do calculations on those values.  For example, you want to transform a date to a presentation value of `mm/dd/yyyy`.  Someone then asks to also show in another location how many days are left until the end of the year for that date.  Then someone asks to change the format to `dd/mm/yyyy` and because you have a dependency on the format your calculation is now wrong without a compiler error :(

Comment: DavidG the above code creates a table that will increment a string. I used this code in MS sql.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you post your code first class i will give better answer. However my presumption is you have you have created it as true way, but i think you missed the [DatabaseGenerated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute which specifies how the database generates values for a property.

It takes [DatabaseGeneratedOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute.databasegeneratedoption(v=vs.110).aspx) which sets the pattern used to generate values for the property in the database and it has the `Identity` options that marks the related property as auto-increment column in your database.

so in your code first `School` class, add the:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

attribute above the `SchoolID` property such this:

```
public class School
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SchoolID { get; set; }

    public string DayEvent { get; set; }
    public string DayNote { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Good Luck! :)

Comment: Your code is not satisfactory for what I need. I need a string that increments and would lie to use data annotations to accomplish it in the code first approach. Thanks for you input.

Comment: @ForrestPhillips, Identities for `string` column types are not supported with `SQL Server`. (How do you expect such a `string` to look like?) To get this working you could - for example - add a computed column/user defined function in `SQL Server` that formats a `string` from an ordinary int identity column - as shown here: http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/custom-sequence-string-as-sql-identity-column.aspx

Comment: Thanks Sahar.H, I am able to get the database to generate the incrementing sting using Emp_ID as 'emp_' + cast(SchoolID as nvarchar(10))Persisted. The database table has the entity Emp_ID {get; set;} when I bring it over into my application via the EF Designer from database. My wish is to be able to use data annotations with Code First to send it back to the sql server database table. You are using a stored procedure which I at the present time have not accomplished learning yet. I have made several stored procedures but do not know how to call them from the database with the controller.

Comment: @ForrestPhillips It cannot be done through current versions of `EF`. maybe in future! :) good luck.